# (Mis)understanding Generators

Tags: python, python-2.7, recursion, python-requests, generator

I want to pull a proxy once at a time from a list that refreshes itself on intervals, and I have no issues with that.

Some of the proxies are no good, and I wish to use the next one from the list. This is where my generator comes in, however, while I can get the generator rolling by calling a .next() the first time, the second time I call it, I get the same value!

Clearly I must be missing a key part in understanding how generators work.

My generator code is inside a `ProxyHandler` class:

```
class ProxyHandler:

    def __init__(self):
        self.proxies = list()
        self.current = dict()

    def get_proxies(self):
        """ Retrieves proxies """

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.proxies)

    def yield_proxy(self):
        if not self.proxies:
            print 'Created new proxy list'
            self.get_proxies()  # This populates self.proxies which is a list of tuples where the 0th element is the host and the 1st element is the port
        for p in self.proxies:
            try:
                proxy = {'http': 'http://%s:%s' % (p[0], p[1])}  # Formatted to python's request lib proxy format
                self.current = proxy
                yield proxy
            except StopIteration:
                print 'Reached end of proxy list'
                self.current = {}
                self.get_proxies()
                yield self.yield_proxy()
```

And usage:

```
def get_response(self, url):
    proxy = self.proxy_handler.current
    if proxy == {}:
        proxy = self.proxy_handler.yield_proxy().next()
    print 'Current proxy -', proxy
    response = url_request(url, proxy=proxy)  # url_request() is basically a modified version of python's requests
    print response
    if response: # url_request() returns true if status code == 200
        return response, proxy
    gen = self.proxy_handler.yield_proxy()
    gen.next()
    return self.get_ebay_response(url)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating the generator afresh each time:

```
gen = self.proxy_handler.yield_proxy()
gen.next()
```

A new generator starts from the beginning; separate generators do not share state. Store the generator somewhere, and then reuse that object to get new values.

You could perhaps store that generator object as an attribute on `self`:

```
proxy_generator = None

def get_response(self, url):
    if not self.proxy:
        if self.proxy_generator is None
            self.proxy_generator = self.proxy_handler.yield_proxy()
        self.proxy = next(self.proxy_generator)
    proxy = self.proxy
```

I used the [`next()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next) to keep your code forward-compatible with Python 3 (which you will have to switch to sooner or later, Python 2 is now a legacy language).

Next, your generator tries to catch an exception that'll never be thrown:

```
for p in self.proxies:
    try:
        proxy = {'http': 'http://%s:%s' % (p[0], p[1])}  # Formatted to python's request lib proxy format
        self.current = proxy
        yield proxy
    except StopIteration:
        print 'Reached end of proxy list'
        self.current = {}
        self.get_proxies()
        yield self.yield_proxy()
```

In your `try` there is no generator being accessed; you gave that job to the `for` loop over `self.proxies`, and `for` *already* knows how to handle an iterator (it'll catch `StopIterator` to end the loop). And `self.proxies` is just a list anyway.

If you wanted to make the loop cycle over your proxies, do so in an endless `while True` loop:

```
while True:
    for p in self.proxies:
        proxy = {'http': 'http://%s:%s' % (p[0], p[1])}  # Formatted to python's request lib proxy format
        self.current = proxy
        yield proxy

    print 'Reached end of proxy list'
    self.current = {}
    self.get_proxies()
```

I'm not sure why you think you need to clear `self.current` there and re-fetch the proxies. The tuple on your generator was never altered, so why re-fetch? And your current proxy is still valid, even if you do start the loop again from the top. I'd drop those last three lines.

You can simplify your code further. A generator has no length, so the `__len__` method is not needed. At best the method produces *wrong* information; your `self.proxies` attribute is empty until you start iterating, so your object has length 0 to start with. Drop the method altogether.

Next, you can give your object an `__iter__` method that produces the generator:

```
class ProxyHandler:
    def __init__(self):
        self.proxies = []
        self.current = {}

    def get_proxies(self):
        """ Retrieves proxies """

    def __iter__(self):
        if not self.proxies:
            print 'Created new proxy list'
            self.get_proxies()
        while True:
            for p in self.proxies:
                proxy = {'http': 'http://%s:%s' % (p[0], p[1])} 
                self.current = proxy
                yield proxy
```

This makes the whole `ProxyHandler` instance an iterable, just use `iter(self.proxy_handler)` instead of `self.proxy_handler.yield_proxy()` to get the generator to produce all those values.

Last but not least, you can use a generator expression for the whole thing, together with [`itertools.cycle()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) to make that iterator endless. You would have to drop the `current` attribute, however, but that shouldn't really matter as you don't actually need that attribute when your generator just yielded the current object *anyway*:

```
from itertools import cycle

class ProxyHandler:
    def __init__(self):
        self.proxies = []

    def get_proxies(self):
        """ Retrieves proxies """

    def __iter__(self):
        if not self.proxies:
            print 'Created new proxy list'
            self.get_proxies()
        return cycle({'http': 'http://%s:%s' % (p[0], p[1])} for p in self.proxies)
```

A generator expression produces the same kind of object.

This all still requires `iter(self.proxy_generator)`; you could make the instance *iterator* (rather than an iterable), by having `__iter__` return `self`, and adding in a `next()` method; move the generator expression above to an attribute on first call, then pass on the `next()` call to that to produce the values:

```
class ProxyHandler:
    def __init__(self):
        self.proxies = []
        self._gen = None

    def get_proxies(self):
        """ Retrieves proxies """

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        if not self._gen:
            self.get_proxies()
            self._gen = cycle({'http': 'http://%s:%s' % (p[0], p[1])} for p in self.proxies)
        return next(self._gen)

    __next__ = next  # Python 3 compatibility
```

Now you can use `next(self.proxy_handler) each time:

```
def get_response(self, url):
    if not self.proxy:
        self.proxy = next(self.proxy_handler)
    proxy = self.proxy
```

Comment: So, in order to solve this I would need to create a generator outside my method and call it when needed?

Comment: @galalmighty: exactly. A generator is a single object that keeps state; don't replace it each time you need a value, keep it around instead.

Comment: Insightful, detailed and very cleared. Thank you! Learnt a lot in around 10 minutes.

Comment: @galalmighty Step debug a simple function that yields several values and you will see.

Comment: @galalmighty In practice, generators are usually used like other iterable objects: `gen = some_generator(); for x in gen: do_something(x)`. That's why you would want to create the generator once and then access it several times. In your case, you could add `self.proxy_gen = self.yield_proxy()` to your `__init__`. Then you could replace `self.proxy_handler.yield_proxy().next()` with `self.proxy_handler.proxy_gen.next()`, which will be an infinite generator.